# what is wrong with this schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi I am developing an application with nodejs and mongoose, I have many schemas and modules that work well, but one I do not understand what is wrong with it.
This is my schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var rel_pv_parSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  "ins_utente": String,
  "ins_data": { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  "pv_id": Number,
  "mod_utente": String,
  "mod_data": { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  "tc_clpar_id": Number,
  "tc_par_id": Number
},{ collection:'rel_pv_par' })

module.exports = rel_pv_parSchema
```

this is my module:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = require('../schemas/rel_pv_par');
var rel_pv_par = mongoose.model('Rel_pv_par', Schema);
module.exports = rel_pv_par;
```

this is how I use my module:

```
var test = require ('tap').test
var rel_pv_par = require('../schemas/rel_pv_par');
var tc_par = require('../schemas/tc_par');
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

test('rel_pv_par',function(t){
  var conn = mongoose.connect('127.0.0.1','saloniTest',27017)
  var Rel_pv_par = conn.model('rel_pv_par', rel_pv_par);

  Rel_pv_par.find({},function(err,out){
    console.log('last out');
    console.log(out)
  })

  t.ok(true,'ok')
  t.end()
})
```

I do not get any output except the one of tap, it looks like the collection is empty, but it is not, after some minutes that the test is running I get this error message:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_2 Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

I should not be complicated, but I am really puzzled, do not understand the error.

Comment: You're running out of memory.  There's a good chance you have an infinite recursion problem in there, somewhere.

Comment: Instead of `var Rel_pv_par = conn.model('rel_pv_par', rel_pv_par);` try `var Rel_pv_par = mongoose.model('rel_pv_par');`

Comment: Run it under a debugger like [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) or keep simplifying your program to track down where it's happening.

Comment: thanks if try var Rel_pv_par = conn.model('rel_pv_par'); I get this error: type:    MissingSchemaError
    message: |
      Schema hasn't been registered for model "rel_pv_par". But if I use an other  schema it works, this is why think the problem is in my schema rel_pv_par

Comment: I made a test I tried to change the collection declared in my schema, changing the collection it works, how is it possible?